# iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found

Tags: swift, app-store, testflight

I'm trying to make test flight in first step I need to upload it on App Store.i do this but finally face with this error :

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.GoogleToolboxForMac' is correct.
```

so what I have done till now :

create app in iTunes.apple

cheek the bundle id of project and the bundle id developer portal and iTunes website

I have create provisioning profile and new bundle id in developer portal

the problem is not bundle id I have cheeked thousand time.

I think problem is GoogleToolboxForMac library but I don't know how to look for library bundle id??

should I wait for approve my app? it is in prepare for submission now

Comment: same problem....

Answer (score 0):

It happens to have the exact same problem, and this started happening today, after I have updated Xcode or iTunes (can't remember which was)

I have check my Bundle ID in both portal and Manifest file and they are both matching

I cannot comment on your thread because i not having 50 reputation